# Json DeserializeObject exception: "reference not set to instance of an object"

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm having trouble deserializing a json string into objects. I have a similar instance working fine for a different class, but i can't seem to get this one to work correctly. Here is the class:

```
    class Task
{
    public string ProviderID { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string CompleteBy { get; set; }
    public string CompleteAtLat { get; set; }
    public string CompleteAtLon { get; set; }
    public string PerformWithin { get; set; }
    public string AdditionalInfo { get; set; }
    public string UserCanReject { get; set; }
    public string StartTime { get; set; }
    public string CompleteTime { get; set; }
    public string ActualCompleteLat { get; set; }
    public string ActualCompleteLon { get; set; }
    public string UserNotes { get; set; }



    public static IList<Task> Get()
    {
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("url");
        req.Method = "GET";
        req.ContentType = "application/json";
        HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string text = sr.ReadToEnd();
            JObject jsonresponse = JObject.Parse(text);
            Console.WriteLine(jsonresponse.ToString());
            IList<JToken> results = jsonresponse["Stasks"].Children().ToList();
            IList<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
            foreach (JToken result in results)
            {
                Task task = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Task>(result.ToString());
                tasks.Add(task);
            }
            return tasks;

        }
    }
```

And here is a sample of the Json string i'm trying to deserialize.

```
    {
   "STasks":[
      {
         "ProviderId":"xxxxx",
         "Id":"xxxxx",
         "UserEmail":"xxxxx",
         "Name":"test",
         "Status":"Completed",
         "CompleteBy":"2014-11-15T15:17:00.0000000Z",
         "CompleteAtLat":0,
         "CompleteAtLon":0,
         "PerformWithin":50,
         "AdditionalInfo":"trsgghghfhghh",
         "UserCanReject":true,
         "STaskActivities":[
            {
               "Instruction":"fsdgggdg",
               "OutcomeId":"00000000000000000000000000000000",
               "CompleteTime":"2014-11-14T15:19:37.0000000Z",
               "ActivityType":"Instruction"
            }
         ],
         "STaskHistories":[
            {
               "EventDate":"2014-11-14T15:18:27.2975697Z",
               "Status":"Draft"
            },
            {
               "EventDate":"2014-11-14T15:18:54.8263294Z",
               "Status":"Sent"
            },
            {
               "EventDate":"2014-11-14T15:19:37.7176027Z",
               "Status":"Accepted"
            },
            {
               "EventDate":"2014-11-14T15:19:49.0975573Z",
               "Status":"Completed"
            }
         ],
         "StartTime":"2014-11-14T15:19:37.0000000Z",
         "CompleteTime":"2014-11-14T15:19:47.0000000Z",
         "ActualCompleteLat":52.6091012845814,
         "ActualCompleteLon":4.75544677437253,
         "UserNotes":"Fyujvhfdkskbvdskbdvsbkdsvhkj"
      }
   ]
}
```

I couldn't find any sort of detailed explanation of how this method works exactly, so maybe i'm missing something here. If i don't have a property in my class but it does appear in the Json, then it should be ignored, right?

Comment: Your json object has STasks and you are specifying Stasks in your code (jsonresponse["Stasks"]).  That might be one issue.

Comment: Also, instead of manually iterate the data just deserialize all the data with Json.net

Comment: the line number where the exception is thrown would help very much. Other then the upper/lower case mismatch @dustmouse found, I don't see anything obvous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you're just parsing up the wrong JSON tree (pun!).

When I map out your JSON into classes, the deserialization works as expected. Try this:

Top-level JSON mapping:

```
public class STasksContainer
{
    public STask[] STasks{get;set;}
}
```

Also add this mapping for the primary array element:

```
public class STask
{
    public string ProviderId {get;set;}
    public string Id{get;set;}
    public string UserEmail{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Status{get;set;}
    public string CompleteBy{get;set;}
    public double CompleteAtLat{get;set;}
    public double CompleteAtLon{get;set;}
    public int PerformWithin{get;set;}
    public string AdditionalInfo{get;set;}
    public bool UserCanReject{get;set;}
    public string StartTime{get;set;}
    public string CompleteTime{get;set;}
    public double ActualCompleteAtLat{get;set;}
    public double ActualCompleteAtLon{get;set;}
    public string UserNotes{get;set;}
    public STaskActivity[] STaskActivities{get;set;}
    public STaskHistory[] STaskHistories{get;set;}
}
```

And lastly, add in the mappings for the two nested array elements within `STask`:

```
public class STaskActivity
{
    public string Instruction{get;set;}
    public string OutcomeId{get;set;}
    public string CompleteTime{get;set;}
    public string ActivityType{get;set;}
} 

public class STaskHistory
{
    public string EventDate{get;set;}
    public string Status{get;set;}
}
```

You can test the code:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()))
{
    string text = sr.ReadToEnd();
    var sTaskRoot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<STasksContainer>(text);
}
```

HTH...!

Comment: This is very helpful! However, there are certain parts of this json string that i don't want to use. Do i have to support them even if i don't have any use for them?

Comment: You could choose to grab a subset and deserialize it, but from practical experience, I've found it much better to just map the entire graph out, if the json is not terribly complex (which in this situation, was not). You can see this observation is borne out by the fact that the effort to deserialize takes you 3 lines of code, and any potential future changes will be to the mapping, not the core logic itself (which you can "black box" at some later juncture).